# How many contribution points do I need to level up my faction rank?

Tags: blade-and-soul

In Blade and Soul you can be one of two factions, and you can gain contribution points to rank up in them.

However, I cant (or dont know how to) tell what my experience points are at, nor how many points are required for my level up.

How do I check how many contribution points I have, and how many I need to get the next rank?

Comment: If I remember correctly faction points level up your faction.

Comment: Note that to have the rank 1 you need 100k points at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "P"(unless you rebound it) menu under the Faction tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can check how much you got at a prestige exchange merchant, look on the right and it will say eg. 420 Faction Contribution Points > 420 FC Points if you have 0 prestige.